How can I match all valid url in Flutter?
I want to parse all valid url in text.But I try many times with different patterns,like given by Microsoft:How To: Use Regular Expressions to Constrain Input in ASP.NET.It works well in RegExr.But when I use it into my Flutter app,it works unsuccessfully.How can I solve this problem?
RegExp pattern = RegExp(r"^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?$");
List<RegExpMatch> matches = pattern.allMatches(text).toList();
/// length is 0
print("length: ${matches.length}")


Remove the anchors, ^ and $.

it looks like you have a lot of unnecessary escaping in your string. I think all \ except the one at \w need to be removed

@Ivo \ in the last group is also required

@KenzoStaelens true

Think you very much.It works well.@WiktorStribiżew

you might still have a few mistakes in your regex, first off (0-9) as a port does not match any port, just a 0 a - or a 9, like mentioned before there are a bunch of unnecessary escapes. furhtermore i believe you have a few too many quantifiers, an unnecessary [0-9a-zA-Z] after already matching \w and your $amp; doesn't get matched as a single entity in your last group. ^(ht|f)tp(s?):\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*)(:[0-9]*)(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9-.?,'/\\+%$#_&]*|&amp;)$ should fix a few of these issues; i'll leave some of the unncessary grouping as is as i assume you use them soewhere

Unfortunately, you cannot tell whether the period following http://example.com. is part of the URL or not.  So at best, this is only a guess.
